# ESLint: Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'jsx, flow, typescript' (2:9)

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb, prettier-eslint, babel-eslint

I am trying to use ESLint in WebStrom, but it doesn't work and displays an error:

> ESLint: Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'jsx, flow, typescript' (2:9).

Here is my `.eslintrc` and `package.json` settings. What should I do for fixing the error?

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "raonair-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "airbnb",
      "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "flowtype"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "allowImportExportEveryWhere": false,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "globalReturn": false,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "babelOptions": {
      "configFile": "./babel.config.js"
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "jsx-a11y",
    "react-hooks",
    "@babel/",
    "flowtype",
    "import"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "groups": [
          "builtin",
          "external",
          "internal",
          "parent",
          "sibling"
        ],
        "newlines-between": "always",
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc",
          "caseInsensitive": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "indent": [
      "error",
      2,
      {
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "no-console": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "error",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    },
    "insert_final_newline": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided us with any other project files than
`.eslintrc(.json)` and `package.json`.
I was not able to reproduce the error message
`Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the
following parser plugin(s): 'jsx, flow, typescript' (2:9)`
but instead got
`Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot find module './babel.config.js'`.

Answer (score 55):

1. Install `@babel/preset-react` in dev dependencies.
2. Add this in .eslintrc file

   ```
    ...
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
       ...
       "babelOptions": {
          "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
       },
      }
    ...
   ```

Source: https://ffan0811.medium.com/error-debugging-this-experimental-syntax-requires-enabling-one-of-the-following-parser-plugin-s-22946599a0a4

Comment: Since `"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",` is already in `.eslintrc(.json)`, there is no need to add it.

Answer (score 43):

To expand on Ceroy's answer ([source](https://ffan0811.medium.com/error-debugging-this-experimental-syntax-requires-enabling-one-of-the-following-parser-plugin-s-22946599a0a4)):

1. Install dependencies needed to enable babel to properly parse jsx

`yarn add @babel/preset-react -D`

or

`npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`

2. Configure Babel

`.babelrc` file in the project root:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

3. Specify parser in `.eslintrc.json` (so your console and VSCode will use the same one) - full eslintrc shown here:

```
{
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "standard",
        "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
        "plugin:testing-library/react",
        "plugin:jest/all"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {}
}
```

Note: `.eslintrc.json` can also be created via `npm init @eslint/config` or by using the ESLint extension in VSCode. The init will give you more options to choose from (such as TypeScript support)

4. Try it out in the console: `npx eslint --fix .`
5. Check VSCode (with the ESLint extension)

Bonus:

ESLint Plugin Settings for VSCode (autofix on save, Jest aware, babel parser etc. - in global VSCode settings.json):

```json
    ...
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.lintTask.enable": true,
    "eslint.options": {
        "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ]
    ...
```

Full `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "okta-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through this error. My problem was the version issue of `eslint-config-standard`.

So my solution is `eslint-config-standard` version downgrade `17.0.0` => `16.0.3`

```
"eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0" => "^16.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but for me what work out is like below. I have added the screenshot of error and steps to resolve it

**Step 1 :**  Install the @babel/preset-react dependancy if already not available in your `package.json` file

```
yarn add @babel/preset-react
```

`package.json` file for reference

```
{
  "name": "animationapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.0.15",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-copilot": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.5.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.26.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**Step 2 :** Add `.eslintrc.js` file with following options aas mentioned below the important line for me is like to add below jsx support

```
parserOpts: {
        plugins: ["jsx"]
      }
```

After adding this into `.eslintrc.js` file it looks like below

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false,
    babelOptions: {
      babelrc: false,
      configFile: false,
      // your babel options
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
      parserOpts: {
        plugins: ["jsx"]
      }
    },
  },
};
```

**Step 3 :** Add `.eslintignore` for ignoring files and folders from linting and add `.babelrc` file as well

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

`.eslintignore` file

```
build/*.js
config/*.js
coverage/*.js
coverage/*
jest/*.js
__tests__/*
__tests__/*.js
```

**Step 4 :** Here before and after adding above setups it works for me running `yarn lint` without any error

[image]

[image]